# Difference between 'app.settings.title' and 'settings.title'

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

If I set the following in my `app.js` file, why can't I access it using `app.settings.title` rather than `settings.title` in my rendered view? It seems I cannot prefix it with the `app` object.

```
...
app.set('title','TestApplication');
...
```

Why must I do this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title><%= settings.title %></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

rather than this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title><%= app.settings.title %></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

There is probably a simply answer to this question, but I am new to Javascript and am trying to learn Expressjs and Nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because variable is extracted before getting to view.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that...?

Comment: Something like this: it stores all variables for e.g. in `app.locals['variable'] = value`, then when you use app.render it passes variables from scope `locals` to render engine. So it never will be `app['variable'] = value` cause of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Because express provides some abstraction at the view level.  It would be redundant and potentially insecure to expose app to your view, and so it's abstracted away so that you can just directly access `settings`.